# convert date time to Epoch format in CSV in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, datetime

I want to convert datetime to Epoch format in csv file using PowerShell. In the csv file I have only time data, and I want to use current date and time specified in csv to convert it to Epoch format .

**in.csv**

```
"192.168.1.2","01-any1TEST ","Ping","Down at least 3 min","17:25:14",":Windows 2012 Server"
"192.168.1.2","02-any2TEST  ","Ping","Down at least 4 min","17:25:40",":Unix Server"
"192.168.1.2","03-any3TEST ","Ping","Down at least 3 min","17:26:21",":windows host "
```

**My findings**

This should be doable using a combination of the below two. The main issue I am facing is that I am unable to combine the current date with the time in csv file.

```
Import-Csv ".\out.csv" |
ForEach-Object {
    $_.Date = [datetime]::Parse($_.Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')
}

Get-Date -Date "12/31/2015 23:59:59" -UFormat %s
```

Comment: You don't need to. If you parse a timestamp in the default system locale format with `[datetime]::Parse()`, it'll assume you meant "today's date" for the date part.

Comment: Nitpick: Please stop saying *"Epoch format"*.  That's not a thing.  Be specific about what output you want.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Get-Date`, you have the option to override values manually or using another `datetime`

For example:

```
Import-Csv ".\out.csv" |
ForEach-Object {
    $tempDate = [datetime]::Parse($_.Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')
    Get-Date -Hour $tempDate.Hour -Minute $tempDate.Minute -UFormat %s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
Import-Csv ".\out.csv" |
ForEach-Object {
    $_.Date = Get-Date -Date $_.Date -UFormat %s
}
```

If you want to be a bit more explicit about what it's doing, you can convert the time to a timespan, which can be added to a date.  Then you can pipe it to Get-Date to format it:

```
Import-Csv ".\out.csv" |
ForEach-Object {
    $_.Date = [DateTime]::Today + [Timespan]::Parse($_.Date) | Get-Date -UFormat %s
}
```

`[DateTime]::Today` is today's date at midnight (time 00:00:00).

---

Ok, try the code below.  It will write a warning message to the console when it finds a date that it can't parse.  It won't fix the problem, but it will tell you where the problem is.

```
Import-Csv ".\out.csv" |
ForEach-Object {
    $t = [timespan]::Zero
    if ([Timespan]::TryParse($_.Date,[ref]$t)) {
        $_.Date = [DateTime]::Today + $t | Get-Date -UFormat %s
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Unable to parse timespan '$($_.Date)' for record $($_)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , 
 Is "17:25:14" is not valid timespan ? Got below error : 
Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan."

Comment: It should be, yes.  I can certainly run `[TimeSpan]::Parse("17:25:14")` at the PowerShell prompt.  Try `$_.Date.Trim()`.  You may need to rewrite it to use  `[timespan]::TryParse()`, but that function is a pain because it uses pass by reference.

Comment: @sachinbhomale Try my updated code.  It may help troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfectly for me in 2.0 and not on 4.0 version . If possible please let me know why is is not working on powershell 4.0 .

```
$EventTime = $($s.EventTime)
```

$value = get-date -format d
$Imported = Import-Csv 'C:\PathToFIle\out.csv'

$Output = foreach ($i in $Imported) {
    foreach ($c in $EventTime) {

```
    $time=$i.eventtime

    $fulltime =$value+' '+$time


     $i.EventTime = Get-Date -Date $fulltime -UFormat %s


}
$i
```

}

$Output
$Output | Export-Csv 'C:\PathToFIle\TestComputers.csv' -NoTypeInformation